# I'm having trouble with a rank command

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, discord.js

I'm trying to make a rank command with Firebase Realtime Database. First, I was having a trouble with the entries, but I believe I solved it. But now I’m having trouble with the "not enough users" message, which is sent all the time. But besides that, if I remove it, the command works, but it says that all users have 0 money. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Json file example:

```
 {
  "Users": {
    "12345678912345678" : {
      "Economy" : {
        money: 500
      }
    },
    "98989898989898989" : {
      "Economy" : {
        money: 100
      }
    },
    "45454545454545454" : {
      "Economy" : {
        money: 9700
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The command:

```
require('firebase').default.database().ref('Users').once('value').then(money => {

  let entries = Object.entries(money.val());

  entries = entries.filter(o => o[1].Economy.money);
  entries.sort((a, b) => b[1].Economy.money - a[1].Economy.money);

  var page = args[0]
  if(!page || isNaN(page) || page > 9) {
    page = 0
    num = 10
  } else {
    page = (args[0] - 1)
    num = page + 10
  }

  if(entries.length < num) return message.channel.send(({embed: {description: `:x: There are not enough users for this page!`, color: 'RED'}}));

  var x = entries.map(([key, value], i) => (i + 1) + ". " + (client.users.cache.get(key) ? client.users.cache.get(key).tag : "Unknown#0000") + "\nMoney: " + (value["money"] || 0) + "\n\n").slice(page, num).join("")

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Global Ranking")
  .setDescription(x)
  .setFooter(`Page ${(!args[0] || isNaN(parseInt(args[0]))) ? 1 : args[0]}`)

  message.channel.send(embed)
})
```

Comment: Are you doing your maths correct? I'd recheck the page and num calculations. `num = page + 10` = 1 + 10 = 11 for page 1, 2 + 10 = 12 for page 2, etc.

Comment: I think it's correct. I don't know much about this page system, but a friend gave it to me and it works correctly. The problem is that the bot is not saying the correct amount of money for each user. I believe the problem is in the variable x.

Comment: I managed to fix it! I changed the `value["money"]` to `value.Economy.money`.
And in the "not enough users" message, I changed the `if(entries.length < num)` to `if(entries.length < page + 10)`
Now everything is working :D